# How to get message id in ios

Tags: ios, swift, email

Is it possible to get message id for email sent using MFMailComposeViewController in ios?

I want to receive a message id to open sent messages:

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "message://%3c4AFF4992-565C-4AE3-AD5E-0D3717B18305@icloud.com%3e")!)
```

Link works. message id received on a computer

I read about this [here](https://medium.com/@vijaysundaram/how-to-deep-link-to-ios-7-mail-6c212bc79bd9)

Comment: No. You can't get anything about the email sent with `MFMailComposeViewController`.